# LINQ (or) Using processing in loop? What to choose?

Tags: c#, linq

I came to a following situation and need to decide which approach CalculateEntrySummaryInArray() (or) CalculateEntrySummaryInLINQ()
 is BEST in terms of

- Better Code
- Code maintainability
- Ability to understand the code
- Performance (The 'List events' contain max 100,000
  events)

Please suggest.

```
 public enum EntryType
    {
        None,
        Entry,
        Exit
    }
public class EventEntity
    {
        public EventEntity()
        {
            Time = new DateTime(0);
            Name = string.Empty;
            Type = EntryType.None;
        }

        public DateTime Time { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public EntryType Type { get; set; }
    }    
    public class EntrySummary
    {
        public EntrySummary()
        {
            Time = new DateTime(0);
            Name = string.Empty;
            Count = 0;
        }

        public DateTime Time { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }

        public void CalculateEntrySummaryInArray(List<EventEntity> events)
        {
            List<EntrySummary> summary = new List<EntrySummary>();

            foreach (var entryEvent in events)
            {
                if (entryEvent.Type != EntryType.Entry) continue;

                if (summary.Count == 0)
                {
                    EntrySummary entrySummary = new EntrySummary();
                    entrySummary.Count = 1;
                    entrySummary.Name = entryEvent.Name;
                    entrySummary.Time = entryEvent.Time;

                    summary.Add(entrySummary);
                }
                else
                {
                    bool isAddedToSummary = false;

                    foreach (var item in summary)
                    {
                        if (item.Name == entryEvent.Name && item.Time.Date == entryEvent.Time.Date)
                        {
                            item.Count++;
                            isAddedToSummary = true; break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (isAddedToSummary == false)
                    {
                        EntrySummary entrySummary = new EntrySummary();
                        entrySummary.Count = 1;
                        entrySummary.Name = entryEvent.Name;
                        entrySummary.Time = entryEvent.Time;

                        summary.Add(entrySummary);
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (var item in summary)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(item.Time.Date.ToString() + " " + item.Name + " " + item.Count);
            }
        }

        public void CalculateEntrySummaryInLINQ(List<EventEntity> events)
        {
            var summary = from entryEvent in events
                     where entryEvent.Type == EntryType.Entry
                     group entryEvent by new { entryEvent.Time.Date, entryEvent.Name} into groupedEvent
                     select new { groupedEvent.Key.Date, groupedEvent.Key.Name, Count = groupedEvent.Count() };

            foreach (var item in summary)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(item.Date.ToString() + " " + item.Name + " " + item.Count);
            }
        }
```

Comment: @BizApps Thanks for editing. I tried formatting code, but I dint get it.

Comment: Highlight your code then ctrl+k .

Comment: Chained LINQ operators can be harder to debug, because you can't see what's happening at each step. I'd still prefer it over the traditional code, because it shows intent, rather than implementation.

Comment: LINQ makes developer to write less code. So the maintenance cost is reduced. So my thought is LINQ is better.

Answer (score 1):

This is an opinion question, and is likely to be closed, but personally I'd take a third approach:

```
foreach (var item in events
        .Where(e => e.Type = EntryType.Entry)
        .GroupBy(e => new { e.Time.Date, e.Name })  // I think, kinda forget
        .Select(ge => new { ge.Key.Date, ge.Key.Name, Count = ge.Count() }))
{
    MessageBox.Show(...);
}
```

I'm not a huge fan of the "select" linq syntax, as I feel like you're jamming a totally different language in there, but I'm not too proud to take advantage of how it works.  Essentially my code is doing the same thing without the syntactic saccharine.

Comment: Also, a non-linq approach is likely to be faster.  Less use of delegates which tends to be expensive, but it's much longer and much less clear, which means maintenance will be worse, especially when you've forgotten what it was supposed to do.

Comment: The MessageBox statement is added just to test. If there is no MessageBox, which approach do you prefer?

Comment: Doesn't matter.  I still think this approach is cleaner.  You're not introducing all of the "special" operators like select, group ... by, etc.  The contents of the loop don't have much bearing on it.

Comment: +1 I completely agree with your sentiments regarding declarative vs method based LINQ. I wish more people would use the latter by default and only resort to the former exceptionally.

Answer (score 0):

The Linq version hands down.  To take just one example, the Linq version probably uses a HashSet internally in its GroupBy implementation for performance reasons.

But the non-linq version is far from optimal with respect to all your criteria you give, so the comparison is hardly fair.